Вывести заголовок объявления яндекс.директ, с которого перешёл пользователь, на страницу
Заказчик дал задание. У него есть объявление в яндекс.директ. Мы должны переходить на сайт и получать заголовок равный заголовку объявления, по которому щёлкнул пользователь. Он формируется динамически то есть. Вот что-то похожее для гугл описывается https://cmsmagazine.ru/journal/news-company-7322/ . Техподдержка директа меня не понимает. Кто-нибудь знает, как это делается?

По-моему даже по вашей ссылке есть чёткое упоминание UTM-меток, хотя там и нагрузили пост бессмысленными картинками и болтологией. Если знать, что искать жить становится проще. Начинаете с  Википедии UTM-метки и двигаетесь дальше. Вот, например, первый попавшийся под руку генератор от Тильды — чтобы лучше представить суть. Осталось прописать их в Директе. Теперь, переходя по рекламным ссылкам эти метки будут в URL в виде запроса. Остаётся их обработать на стороне вашего сервера на ваш вкус.
